# Listing unmounted volumes

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, volumes

I'm looking to make a small menu-bar app to mount/unmount both internal and USB drives. I'm new to Swift/Cocoa so it's a bit a of a learning curve.

I can get a list of mounted volumes using the `FileManager().mountedVolumeURLs(...)` method, but I'm struggling to find a way to get a list of unmounted volumes, and I can't seem to find any resources showing how it's done. Anyone know of a method to do this or can point me towards anything useful?

I'm guessing I'll be using DiskArbitration to mount/unmount once I have a list of the available drives.

Thanks.